# Customer migration with Password, Magento to Prestashop

Tags: magento, passwords, migration, export, prestashop

It's my first post here so I apologize in advance if I've done anything wrong.

Anyhow:

I'm currently working with a customer that wants to migrate from a current `Magento` site to `Prestashop`. My problem is that i can't find a solution for migrating the current users passwords to the new site.

As far as i understand, `Prestashop` and `Magento` uses different password hashing(with salt) and to be able to migrate them i need to decrypt the current ones from `Magento` and then add them to `Prestashop`. My idea to approach this was by decrypting passwords from the database to a CSV file by running a CLI script and then import from CSV to `Prestashop`.

However, i've found a couple of solutions for exporting customer data but nothing with passwords. How do i approach this?

It doesn't have to be a decryption approach, an alternative with implementing Magentos password validator or something like that would be okay.. but i don't know how to do this since i'm new to both `Magento` and `Prestashop`.

All in all, how can i solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think they're encrypted? I bet they are hashed and if so, there is no possibility to retrieve the original passwords - which is the very idea of hashing. You need to read about the very basics of password storing before you attempt to do anything with them, because you clearly lack a basic understanding of the problem. When you do that, you will immediately find the answer to your question.

Comment: You're correct, they're hashed. Wrong usage of terms on my behalf, sorry. So, if i can't retrieve them- then i suppose the only solution is to validate them by implementing Magentos password validator in some way, or generate new passwords? / Send a link to current users to create new passwords?

Comment: As you say, first way (much expensive): implement the magento password hashing system and checking (obviously), at the 'first' login in prestashop you can save the password in the prestashop hashing system. Second way (much much cheaper): import the customers and after the migrating send an e-mail that you tell to customer to re-generate the password.

Comment: have a look at this post, maybe it will help you out: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/611242-module-magento-to-prestashop-17-migration-migrate-customers-with-passwords-products-more/